# RDP not working in Linux after patching MS12-020

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

Our company recently applied patches for a Microsoft vulnerability ([MS12-020 - Vulnerabilities in Remote Desktop Could Allow Remote Code Execution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-020)) which affected RDP to Windows servers.

Since this I've have difficulty with clients connecting to the server. Originally I was unable to connect XP machines but we fixed that following [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951608). I'm still unable to connect with a Linux machine.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) has support for "Credential Security Support Provider (CredSSP)" which is what you now need in order to access your servers via RDP.

Comment: Thanks so much, this has been driving me crazy. This solved it!

Comment: Also encountering ""Failed to connect, CredSSP required by server." in `rdesktop`  (rdesktop-1.8.3-2.fc23). At [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/rdesktop/support-requests/198/), Henrik Andersson says: _"Make sure to initialize a kerberos ticket to be able to connect using CredSSP. There are a lot of guides out there how to do configure a linux kerberos client for Windows Active Directory."_ Well, I didn't find out what that means nor a guide, but installing package `freerdp` works for me.

Comment: Find the FreeRDP Manual [here](https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/User/FreeRDP-User-Manual.markdown). Otherworldy Windows command line syntax: `xfreerdp /v:$SERV:$PORT /size:1920x1080 /u:$USER /p:$PASS /compression`

Comment: See also [Security Support Provider Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface), [Credential Security Support Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [How to Enable (and why not disable) Network Level Access for Windows RDP](https://www.virtuesecurity.com/blog/enable-network-level-access-windows-rdp/) for background info.